# RShiny: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context

Tags: r, shiny

I've looked everywhere for the solution for this, but I just can't figure out how to get rid of the `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.` error in RShiny for my situtation. Here's my server code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Surprisingly there is no correlation between charged kw and time
s <- data[,14:16]
s <- s[complete.cases(s),]
cor(s$charged_kwh, s$connected_time_hours)

car_types <- data %>% group_by(car) %>% 
  summarise(nrUsers = n_distinct(user_id), n=n()) %>% 
  filter(car!="Unknown", car!= " ") %>% 
  arrange(desc(nrUsers))

# Connected hours vs actually charging hours
carged_cars <- reactive({
  data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(charged_kwh)) %>%
  mutate(charging_time =  charged_kwh / kw_charge_point_speed)
})

filteredData <- carged_cars()[carged_cars()$start_date >= input$cvc_date_diagram[1] & carged_cars()$start_date <= input$cvc_date_diagram[2] &
  carged_cars()$connected_time_hours <= input$cvc_max,]

connTimeVsStart <- ggplot(reactive(filteredData), aes(x=start_date, y=connected_time_hours)) +
  geom_point(shape=16) +
  geom_point(reactive(filterData), aes(x=start_date, y=charging_time), col='red') +
  ggtitle("Charging time")

output$connTimeVsStart <- renderPlot({
  d <- data()
  connTimeVsStart
})
```

`data` here, is a dataframe that contains data about electric car charging behavior. The console says that my script crashes at line 20 of this server script, so the part where `filteredData` is defined. I feel like I've tried every combination of making source variables reactive or not, using `reactive({})` vs `reactive()`, etc. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't work ?
    filteredData <- reactive({
        req(carged_cars())
        req(input$cvc_date_diagram)
        carged_cars()[carged_cars()$start_date >= input$cvc_date_diagram[1] & carged_cars()$start_date <= input$cvc_date_diagram[2] &
        carged_cars()$connected_time_hours <= input$cvc_max,]
    })

Comment: @qfazille Nope. It did move the error to line 25 though, the `ggplot` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this piece of code can help you.

**NB :**
 1/ I don't see any use of `car_types`
 2/ I don't know where your variable `data` is created

```
library(ggplot2)

# Surprisingly there is no correlation between charged kw and time
s <- data[,14:16]
s <- s[complete.cases(s),]
cor(s$charged_kwh, s$connected_time_hours)

car_types <- data %>% group_by(car) %>% 
  summarise(nrUsers = n_distinct(user_id), n=n()) %>% 
  filter(car!="Unknown", car!= " ") %>% 
  arrange(desc(nrUsers))

# Connected hours vs actually charging hours
carged_cars <- reactive({
  data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(charged_kwh)) %>%
  mutate(charging_time =  charged_kwh / kw_charge_point_speed)
})

filteredData <- reactive({
    req(carged_cars())
    req(input$cvc_date_diagram)
    carged_cars()[carged_cars()$start_date >= input$cvc_date_diagram[1] & carged_cars()$start_date <= input$cvc_date_diagram[2] &
        carged_cars()$connected_time_hours <= input$cvc_max,]
})

connTimeVsStart <- reactive({
    ggplot(filteredData(), aes(x=start_date, y=connected_time_hours)) +
        geom_point(shape=16) +
        geom_point(reactive(filterData), aes(x=start_date, y=charging_time), col='red') +
        ggtitle("Charging time")
})

output$connTimeVsStart <- renderPlot({
  connTimeVsStart()
})
```